# I need help converting .py file to .exe file

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, exe, pyqt5

I am trying to convert a .py file to .exe file using cx-freeze. I have installed cx-freeze and have added python to my computer path. However, Using the code below, i am supposed to locate the qwindows.dll file in python33. I can't seem to find the file, not only that, i cant seem to find the platforms folder. I have tried uninstalling pyqt4 and reinstalling it using an installer and also installing pyqt5. I still cant find the folder/file...Nothing works??!!!

The code i used is here:

```
import sys

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = "Win64GUI"
path_platforms = ( "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll", "platforms\qwindows.dll" )###Find directory of qwindows.dll###
build_options = {"includes" : [ "re", "atexit" ], "include_files" : [ path_platforms ]}

setup(
    name = "Starters 'R' Us", ###Janu change your name here###
    version = "0.1",
    description = "Maths Assessment System",
    options = {"build_exe" : build_options},
    executables = [Executable("MyProgram.py", base = base,shortcutName="Starters 'R' Us",shortcutDir="DesktopFolder")]###Change the .py file to yours.###
    )
###the shortcut creates shortcut on your desktop###
```